# Switch y-axis to right side using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, gtable

I'm creating a 1 x 2 figure in ggplot2, and want to place the y-axis for one of the figures on the right side of the plot.  I've almost got it, here is a MWE,

```
#Fake data
  x = data.frame(
    values = c(runif(100, min = -2), runif(100), runif(100, max = 2), runif(100)),
    sample = rep(c('sample\na', 'sample\nb'), each = 200),
    flag = sample(c('15C', '25C'), 400, replace = TRUE)
  )

#Make grobs
  p1 = ggplot(subset(x,flag=='15C'),aes(sample,values)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~flag) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())
  p2 = ggplot(subset(x,flag=='25C'),aes(sample,values)) + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~flag) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0))

#Change position of y-axis for p2
  g = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

#Find axis grob and make adjustments
  ia = which(g$layout$name == "axis_l-1")
  ax = g$grobs[[ia]]$children[[2]]
  ax$widths = rev(ax$widths)
  ax$grobs = rev(ax$grobs)
  pp = c(subset(g$layout,name=="panel-1",select=t:r))
  g = gtable_add_cols(g,g$widths[g$layout[ia, ]$l],length(g$widths)-1)
  g = gtable_add_grob(g,ax, pp$t,length(g$widths)-1,pp$b)
  g$grobs[[ia]]$children[[2]] = NULL
  g$widths[[3]] = unit(0,'cm')

#Plot it out
  windows(height=4,width=8)
  grid.draw(cbind(ggplotGrob(p1),g,size='last'))
```

However, the axis.tick.margin for the plot on the right is screwed up (see figure below).  I would prefer to somehow automate this.  I've searched for old hacks, but they seem to have broke with the upgrade to ggplot2 v2.0.0.  Any advice?

[image]

Comment: `ax$grobs[[2]][["children"]][[1]][["x"]] <- ax$grobs[[2]][["children"]][[1]][["x"]] + unit(1,"mm")`

Comment: @baptiste Thanks!  That did the trick.  I also noticed that the ticks marks are a little off, do you know how to fix those?